# How can I add these bones to my meta human? Or is there a way I can make virtual bones count when retargetting?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, skeletal-animation, rigging, bones

Paid for animations thinking they would be fine and they mostly are but... the hands are using these IK bones that I do not have. Is there a way I can add the bones to my meta skeleton within unreal? I tried creating virtual bones but they dont seem to come up in the retarget manager :( Also, I can only seem to add one virtual bone to the root whereas both the foot and hand IK root bones are parented to the root bone here.

[image]

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to open the skeleton in Blender (or other studio) to fix this. There are some tutorials about that.

Comment: Aye thanks for replying. My PC is not very powerful and I've had a few nightmares trying to work on this in blender and then putting it back into unreal. Was hoping there would be another solution in unreal that I wasn't aware of as I am a noob when it comes to this software. Ah well. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm also interested in this, did you managed to do it?